# No layers in the exported image of the MXD project using C#

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I have created a console application to export the active view of an MXD document using C# ArcObjects. The app works, but for some reason the exported image is missing all the layers in the map and legend. I checked, all layers are enabled, the problem is in the export implementation.

```cs
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Output;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Resources;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMap;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;

namespace firstConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static LicenseInitializer m_AOLicenseInitializer = new firstConsole.LicenseInitializer();

        [STAThread()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
            //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
            m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic },
            new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { });
            //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
            //Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication()
            m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();

            IPrintAndExport export = new PrintAndExportClass();

            string mxd = @"C:\0_Work\Test\3.mxd";

            tagRECT exporterRectangle;
            exporterRectangle.left = 0;
            exporterRectangle.bottom = 1654;
            exporterRectangle.top = 0;
            exporterRectangle.right = 2340;
            var expOptions = new ExportJPEGClass();
            expOptions.Quality = 75;
            expOptions.Resolution = 200;
            IMapDocument pMapDocument = new MapDocumentClass();
            expOptions.ExportFileName = mxd.Replace("mxd", "jpg");
            pMapDocument.Open(mxd, null);
            IActiveView activeView = pMapDocument.ActiveView;
            export.Export(activeView, expOptions, 200, false, null);
            pMapDocument.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the PageLayout of yourMapDocumentClass object instead of the active view? The PageLayout class is also an IActiveView, so you're guaranteed to get the layout view and not the "map view".